# two div boxes [1st float, 2nd clear], margin on 2nd doesn't seem to push off first

Tags: html, css

In the code below I have two div boxes.  The first is float:left, the second has clear:left so that it sits below the first.  My question is why does margin-top:20px not push off the first div?

```
<head>
 <style>
 div { width:100px; height:100px; background-color:green; }
 #box1 { float:left; }
 #box2 { background-color:red; clear:left; margin-top:20px; }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="box1"></div>
 <div id="box2"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't know why too, but if you set `margin-bottom:20px;` in `#box1` instead of `margin-top:20px;` in `#box2` you will get the expected result. Maybe it can help you to find the reason. When you find, please share it with us.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's confusing. Read the [CSS spec on collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins).

Specifically,

"If the top and bottom margins of an element with clearance are adjoining, its margins collapse with the adjoining margins of following siblings but that resulting margin does not collapse with the bottom margin of the parent block."

To get the effect you're looking for you need to apply the margin to an element that doesn't have clearance, in this case the first div, like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/6bfYU/

Comment: I'm not sure what your quoted sentence has to do with the situation given. The element with clearance is, as you point out, the second element, which happens to be the last in-flow child. It only has a top margin, and that margin isn't adjoining with anything.

Comment: Ah, you're right. This isn't really margin-collapse. It's just the normal behavior of floats. They aren't really there as far as margins are concerned. You can see the margin being applied in inspector tools. The math is explained here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-clear

Comment: It looks like the clearance is just enough for the top margin to outright disappear altogether, and for the second element to be flush with the float. I'm not entirely familiar with how the clearing algorithm works, though...

Comment: This is one of the really confusing things about the box model. Margin adds to the dimensions of an element, but it *doesn't* add to what the W3C calls the "border edge": http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#box-dimensions . And it's the *border edge* that's being cleared, not the *margin edge*.

Comment: The second element's margin-edge isn't flush with the float. It's *above* it. Look at it with an inspector. The margin is not disappearing, really. It's just that the linked definition (2nd comment) of `clear` specifies that it's the border-edge being cleared. Please accept my answer or explain.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't clear in my comment - I was indeed referring to the border edge. Anyway, I can't accept your answer because I'm not the asker (and I can't do it as a mod either)...